# My application does not start - I get a firebase error with login

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-maps-android-api-2

I have the following error
what file can be making the conflict?

This is the error

1. **this error**

Error log no run

```
it.unipi.iet.namefirebase V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
it.unipi.iet.namefirebase W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
it.unipi.iet.namefirebase W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
com.google.android.gms I/AuthChimeraService: Executing request: ProxyRequest[ url: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?alt=proto&key=AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, method: 1 ]
com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GLSUser: [DeviceKeyStore] Cannot load key: Device key file not found.
? D/WVCdm: Instantiating CDM.
system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
? I/WVCdm: CdmEngine::OpenSession
? I/WVCdm: Level3 Library Sep 28 2015 13:08:28
? W/WVCdm: Could not read /data/mediadrm/IDM1013/ay64.dat2: No such file or directory
? W/WVCdm: Could not load liboemcrypto.so. Falling back to L3.  dlopen failed: library "liboemcrypto.so" not found
? I/WVCdm: CdmEngine::QueryKeyControlInfo
? W/WVCdm: BufferReader::Read<T> : Failure during parse: Not enough bytes (4)
? W/WVCdm: CdmEngine::ExtractWidevinePssh: Unable to read atom size.
? I/WVCdm: CdmEngine::GenerateKeyRequest
? D/WVCdm: PrepareKeyRequest: nonce=331363162
? I/WVCdm: CdmEngine::CloseSession
? W/Binder_3: type=1400 audit(0.0:36): avc: denied { search } for name="1337" dev="proc" ino=4186 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:zygote:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
com.google.android.gms.unstable D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xaa3f7da0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
com.google.android.gms.unstable D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa3f7da0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaa13d7d0)
com.google.android.gms.unstable D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xaa3f8dc0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
com.google.android.gms.unstable D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa3f8dc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaa13d7d0)
? W/Binder_3: type=1400 audit(0.0:37): avc: denied { read } for name="/" dev="tmpfs" ino=2985 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout:
com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:    com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:13)
com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout:
com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:    com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:13)
com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GLSUser: [AppCertManager] IOException while requesting key: 
                                             java.io.IOException: Invalid device key response.
                                                 at ewg.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:11)
                                                 at ewg.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:63)
                                                 at ewg.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:20)
                                                 at ewe.a(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:4)
                                                 at ewe.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:4)
                                                 at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                 at buy.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:3)
                                                 at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GLSUser: [DeviceKeyStore] Cannot load key: Device key file not found.
com.google.android.gms W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout:
com.google.android.gms W/Conscrypt:    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.google.android.gms W/Conscrypt:    com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:13)
com.google.android.gms W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout:
com.google.android.gms W/Conscrypt:    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.google.android.gms W/Conscrypt:    com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@11509470:13)
com.google.android.gms E/Volley: [407] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?alt=proto&key=AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
com.google.android.gms I/AuthChimeraService: Error description received from server: OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED
it.unipi.iet.namefirebase D/MainActivity: signInAnonymously:onComplete:false
it.unipi.iet.namefirebase D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
it.unipi.iet.namefirebase E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getProviderId()' on a null object reference
                                             at it.unipi.iet.namefirebase.MainActivity$4$1.onComplete(MainActivity.java:112)
                                             at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
it.unipi.iet.namefirebase D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, timestamp=1509387653081, fatal=1}]
it.unipi.iet.namefirebase V/FA: Using measurement service
it.unipi.iet.namefirebase V/FA: Connecting to remote service
com.google.android.gms W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess starts
com.google.android.gms W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneNumberAuthPostProcessor] postProcess ends
it.unipi.iet.namefirebase E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                      Process: it.unipi.iet.namefirebase, PID: 3983
                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getProviderId()' on a null object reference
                                          at it.unipi.iet.namefirebase.MainActivity$4$1.onComplete(MainActivity.java:112)
                                          at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity it.unipi.iet.namefirebase/.MainActivity
? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 1806336
it.unipi.iet.namefirebase I/FirebaseCrash: Sending crashes

                                     [ 10-30 18:20:53.326  1771: 2105 D/         ]
                                     HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9d2fe140, tid 2105


                                     [ 10-30 18:20:53.341  1771: 2105 W/         ]
                                     Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1207: eglCreateSyncKHR(1881): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 462294 , only wrote 461378
? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 461380 , only wrote 461378
? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 462078 , only wrote 462039
system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
system_process I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
system_process D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9f70ede0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
system_process D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9f70ede0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9df77ab0)
system_process D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9f70ede0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9df77ab0)
it.unipi.iet.namefirebase I/FirebaseCrash: Response code: 200
it.unipi.iet.namefirebase I/FirebaseCrash: Report sent with crash report id: b8d1495fb4000000    



}
```

**Code mainactivity**

```
   package it.unipi.iet.namefirebase;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import iit.unipi.iet.namefirebase.utilities.AuthUtilities;
import it.unipi.iet.namefirebase.utilities.DatabaseUtilities;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;



public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    public static final String SIGN = "it.unipi.iet.namefirebase.SIGN";
    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private AuthUtilities AuthUt;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Check Authentication
        AuthUt = new AuthUtilities();
        if(AuthUt.getUser() != null ){
            // if user is already logged changes activity
            Log.d(TAG,"User already logged");
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);}
        else{
            Log.d(TAG,"User not logged yet");
            }

        // Sign in Button
        final Button SignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        SignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(SIGN,"sign-in");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Sign up with email Button
        final Button SignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        SignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(SIGN,"sign-up");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Connect with Facebook button
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
                // ...
            }
        });

        // Browse as a guest button
        final Button GuestUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        GuestUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // signin_anonymously
                AuthUt.get_mAuth().signInAnonymously()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                                Log.d(TAG,"User Provider: "+ AuthUt.get_mAuth().getCurrentUser().getProviderId());
                                // start MapsActivity
                                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);

                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "signInAnonymously", task.getException());
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }


                            }
                        });
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        AuthUt.addListner();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        AuthUt.removeListener();
    }

    /*
     * Disable going back function
     */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // disable going back to the previous Activity
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());

        AuthUt.get_mAuth().signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                        FirebaseUser user = AuthUt.get_mAuth().getCurrentUser();
                        Log.d(TAG,"url "+user.getPhotoUrl());
                        DatabaseUtilities db = new DatabaseUtilities();
                        db.writeNewUser(user.getUid(),user.getDisplayName(),null,user.getPhotoUrl().toString(),null, null);
                        Log.d(TAG,"Fb user created");
                        // start MapsActivity
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
    }




}
```

Comment: send it but it does not respond